# how to search "referencesMany" field by array of documents

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine

we have a referenceMany field in Document. In db it becomes an array of ids of documents being referenced.

> @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="GeoLocation", storeAs="id", simple=true)

Now we want to search in this collection for documents referencing documents A or B or C.

**1) The first intuitive approach** would be to do something like `$queryBuilder->field('geo')->references([A,B,C])`

but it seems that "references" only accepts single document, not arrays of them.

**2) The other intuitive approch** would be to use ->in, but it only accepts values, not references.

**3) The last thing** we would want to do is to use a combination of ORs. We should avoid it as it seems to produce inefficient queries (through it's only our guess)

The question is whatis the best way to compose such a query?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be simpler than I thought.

simply do field search by referencing field with **IN** expression with the array of Ids.

```
$qb=$this->createQueryBuilder();
foreach($documents as $document) {
    $geoIds[] = $document->getId();
}
$qb->field('targetGeo')->in($geoIds);
```

we kept on looking for solution because it turned out that OR-based query (option 3) seemed not to use index.

I don't know if this ->in approach is documented, didn't find it. If anyone can point out some documentation about this trick that would be really helpful.